# JQuery :contains not works with html strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div like this

```
<div parent_name='level1.3'><span>level1.3.1</span></div>
```

Now I am trying in JQuery

```
$("div:contains('level1.3.1')").show()

$("div:contains('<span>level1.3.1</span>')").show()
```

First One works but second one fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:contains()` escapes html entities, so you have to use `:has()` first, to check if that div has the span, and then check if that span `:contains()` the required text.

```
$("div:has(span:contains(level1.3.1))").show()
```

Comment: @Raj Haha, lost it. Thanks :)

Comment: I got it, you missed to close parenthesis.Please correct it

Comment: @Mani Noticed it too, just did it :)

Comment: Is there any possibilities to check the text with HTML tags

Comment: @Mani You could loop with `.each()` and check if `.html()` of each element contains `<span>level1.3.1</span>`.